# Create dataframe from rdd objectfile

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

What is the method to create ddf from an RDD which is saved as objectfile. I want to load the RDD but I don't have a java object, only a structtype I want to use as schema for ddf.

I tried retrieving as Row

```
    val myrdd = sc.objectFile[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]("/home/bipin/"+name)
```

But I get

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Is there a way to do this.

**Edit**

From what I understand, I have to read rdd as array of objects and convert it to row. If anyone can give a method for this, it would be acceptable.

Comment: @Anda There was no java object. It was retrieved as a jdbcrdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Array of Object you only have to use the Row apply method for an array of Any. In code will be something like this:

```
val myrdd = sc.objectFile[Array[Object]]("/home/bipin/"+name).map(x => Row(x))
```

**EDIT**

you are rigth @user568109 this will create a Dataframe with only one field that will be an Array to parse the whole array you have to do this:

```
val myrdd = sc.objectFile[Array[Object]]("/home/bipin/"+name).map(x => Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq))
```

As @user568109 said there are other ways to do this:

```
val myrdd = sc.objectFile[Array[Object]]("/home/bipin/"+name).map(x => Row(x:_*))
```

No matters which one you will because both are wrappers for the same code:

```
  /**
   * This method can be used to construct a [[Row]] with the given values.
   */
   def apply(values: Any*): Row = new GenericRow(values.toArray)

  /**
   * This method can be used to construct a [[Row]] from a [[Seq]] of values.
   */
   def fromSeq(values: Seq[Any]): Row = new GenericRow(values.toArray)
```

Comment: It's that simple !! This works but not quite. The rdd I get has a row element which contains Java object wrapper which contains the elements I need. But thanks for the answer. I cannot imagine why the Spark developers chose two different rdds despite being convertible to other.

Comment: I think _* expansion is required for removing the wrapper. Make the change and I will accept your answer.

Comment: oops.. I didnt see there was an answer

Comment: You are rigth @user568109 i eddited my answer

Comment: This would work but I was saying `Row(x:_*)` is easier to write

Comment: @user568109 eddited again with a litle explanation of both methods

Answer (score 0):

Let me add some explaination,

suppose you have a mysql table grocery with 3 columns (item,category,price) and its contents as below

```
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| grocery_id | item    | category | price |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|          1 | tomato  | veg      |  2.40 |
|          2 | raddish | veg      |  4.30 |
|          3 | banana  | fruit    |  1.20 |
|          4 | carrot  | veg      |  2.50 |
|          5 | apple   | fruit    |  8.10 |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, within spark you want to read it, your code will be something like below

```
val groceryRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, ()=> DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,passwd), "select item,price from grocery limit ?,?",1,10,2,r => r.getString("item")+"|"+r.getString("price"))
```

**Note :** 
In the above statement i converted the ResultSet into String **r => r.getString("item")+"|"+r.getString("price")**

So my JdbcRDD will be as

```
groceryRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD[String] = JdbcRDD[29] at JdbcRDD at <console>:21
```

now you save it.

```
groceryRDD.saveAsObjectFile("/user/cloudera/jdbcobject")
```

**Answer to your question**

while reading the object file you need to write as below,

```
val newJdbObjectFile = sc.objectFile[String]("/user/cloudera/jdbcobject")
```

In a blind manner ,just **substitute the type Parameter of RDD you are saving**.

In my case, groceryRDD has a type parameter as String, hence i have used the same

**UPDATE:**

In your case, as mentioned by jlopezmat, you need to use **Array[Object]**

Here **each row of RDD will be Object**, but since you have **converted that using ObjectArray** each row with its contents will be again saved as Array,

i.e, In my case , if save above RDD as below,

```
val groceryRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, ()=> DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,passwd), "select item,price from grocery limit ?,?",1,10,2,r => JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray(r))
```

when i read the same using and collect data

```
val newJdbcObjectArrayRDD = sc.objectFile[Array[Object]]("...")
val result = newJdbObjectArrayRDD.collect
```

result will be of type **Array[Array[Object]]**

```
result: Array[Array[Object]] = Array(Array(raddish, 4.3), Array(banana, 1.2), Array(carrot, 2.5), Array(apple, 8.1))
```

you can parse the above based on your column definitions.

Please let me know if it answered you question

Comment: My data isn't just string which is an issue. I have different types in my row. I have to use JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray in place of your `r.getString`, so it becomes tricky to use this.